# How to serve multiple locations from a single root?

Tags: nginx

I'm having nginx serve static files that map from uri paths to folder paths like:

```
www.tempuri.org/js <=> /var/www/plublic/js
www.tempuri.org/css <=> /var/www/plublic/css
www.tempuri.org/img <=> /var/www/plublic/img
www.tempuri.org/foobar <=> /var/www/plublic/foobar
```

In my nginx conf, the rules for this, essentially all have the same root:

```
location /js/ {
   root /var/www/public/;
}
location /css/ {
   root /var/www/public/;
}
location /foobar/ {
   root /var/www/public/;
}
location /img/ {
   root /var/www/public/;
}
```

How can I write a single rule for all 4 paths?

```
location /(css|js|img|foobar)/ {
   root /var/www/public
}
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root` should be placed in the `server` block, not in the `location` block. This is one of the [most common nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/).

Making this change will also fix your issue and eliminate the *need* for that `location` block.

Comment: Great! So followup question: in my single server tempuri.org, I'm serving two different apps, that each have seperate root paths? How would I accomplish this, using that same notion of having a single root path?

Comment: The other app can use a different `root`, or more likely an `alias`. Depending on the characteristics of the app. But like you said, that really is a separate question. The `root` that appears in the `server` block is the default, and applies to any `location` that doesn't explicitly specify one.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much have it.

```
location ~ ^/(css|js|img|foobar)/ {
    root /var/www/public/;
}
```